# Why using timer_settime() affects on sleep() function

Tags: c, linux, timer

I'm trying to create periodic timer with callback function, it works well. But in main() I've sleep() function and it doesn't work as usually. Instead of sleeping for 10 seconds, it just sleeps for 500 ms, which time is set for timer_settime() function. Is it a bug, or normal behaviour?

```c
volatile sig_atomic_t timer_flag = false;
volatile int total_cnt = 0;
timer_t gTimerid;

void start_timer(void)
{
    struct itimerspec value;
    value.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    value.it_value.tv_nsec = 500000000;
    value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 500000000;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, &gTimerid);
    timer_settime(gTimerid, 0, &value, NULL);
}

void stop_timer(void)
{
    struct itimerspec value;
    value.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    value.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    timer_settime(gTimerid, 0, &value, NULL);
}

void timer_callback(int sig) 
{
    timer_flag = true;  
}

static void *count(void *ptr)
{   
    for(;;) {
        if(timer_flag == true) {                    
            timer_flag = false;
            printf("%d\n", total_cnt++);
        }
        usleep(1000);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{   
    (void) signal(SIGALRM, timer_callback);
    start_timer();

    pthread_t thread_cnt;
    int thread_num = 1;

    pthread_create(&thread_cnt, NULL, count, (void*)&thread_num);

    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    struct timeval  tv1, tv2;

    for(;;) {
        printf("Main loop\n");
        gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);           
        sleep(10);
        gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
        printf ("Total time = %f seconds\n",
         (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
         (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal (=working as standardized). `sleep` is an interruptible blocking function.

[Here's what POSIX says about it:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html)

> If sleep() returns because the requested time has elapsed, the value
>   returned shall be 0. If sleep() returns due to delivery of a signal,
>   the return value shall be the "unslept" amount (the requested time
>   minus the time actually slept) in seconds.

If you want sleep uninterrupted, you need to block signals (or you need to sleep again with the remaining time after the first call is interrupted, but then you'll likely want a higher-resolution sleeping function such as [nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) or [clock_nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html)).